# Getting latest record in a given timeframe

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI heat map that measures the uptime of equipment for the current hour and each of the 8 hours prior:

[image]

The problem lies in the fact that a given hour may not always have records; in the above example, the machine was running from 4 AM to 6 AM non-stop and did not have any records for the 5 AM hour to indicate that it had been up and running that entire hour. The -3 hour should be showing 100% but it is incorrectly showing 0%.

This visualization has a separate measure for each hour, calculating the uptime for each hour. For example, Hour -3 has a calculation as follows:

```
-3 = IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(UptimeCombined), FILTER(UptimeCombined, UptimeCombined[Hours_Offset] = 3))) = TRUE,
(CALCULATE('UptimeCombined'[Uptime %], FILTER(UptimeCombined, UptimeCombined[Hours_Offset] > 3 && UptimeCombined[ShiftDateTime] = MAX(UptimeCombined[ShiftDateTime])))),
(CALCULATE('UptimeCombined'[Uptime %], FILTER('UptimeCombined', 'UptimeCombined'[Hours_Offset] = 3))))
```

If the row count comes back BLANK, then I need to look BACKWARD in time (max record where Hour_Offset > 3) and find the status (either "RN" or "DN") of whatever the last record was and display that uptime value for that hour (100% or 0%, respectively) but I can't get that part of the measure to work properly; the -3 hour should show 100% because the latest record before then had status of "RN" (in the -4 hour). Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

What is the correct DAX I need in Line 2 of this measure to set the uptime to either 100% or 0%, based on the latest record from before that hour?

Comment: You will need to look at the status change only. As I see from your raw data, there is an RN and DN. I assume this is the moment the machine runs/stops? if so, you need to calculate for each hour the minutes it was running. This is not a measure but a table (query)what you need to create first. Based on this data it will be easy to implement your overview.

Comment: Hi @Aldert, you are correct about the RN/DN, and after thinking about your comment, I think it may simpler to just fill in the data gaps using Power Query somehow. That said, my experience coding in M is zero... Do you have any suggestions there?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up filling in the data gaps in the source view on the SQL Server side before the data ever hits Power BI... much simpler that way than trying to mess with complex calculations and measures.